# Is there a difference between npm install on windows & linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

i think i have a short question.

I can't find anything in the www. if i run `npm install` on a windows machine to install my dependencies. is it possible to move the `node_module` directory to a linux machine and run my nodejs script, or is npm checking before installing my os and choose other install path's?

greetings mok

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there can be differences, say, if you (or your dependencies) use native node.js addons, which are built e.g. by node-gyp and contain native binary code. Also there can be OS/CPU - specific stuff in `package.json`.

package.json description can be found here:
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json