# How to best transfer a React project from Windows to Linux

Tags: reactjs, linux, windows

I have several simple React projects that I have built using create-react-app on Windows 10 and wish to transfer them to my Linux development system. I don't think it's as simple as zip and unzip. Can someone suggest the appropriate way to do this? Or should the above mentioned zip/unzip work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever used `git`?

Comment: Yes Alserda  I have  used git

Comment: Have you tried pushing your project to git, pulling it on your Linux machine and running `npm install` to get your dependencies?

Comment: No I haven't tried that, but I will do and will let you know the result, thank you.

Comment: Hi Alserda, I didn't need to use git after all, it seems I only needed to re-install the dependencies as you suggested using 'npm install' ( after unzipping my projects ). If you can make a formal answer I will gladly accept it. Thank you so much for your help and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you get the source code over, anything is fine really. A recommended way of doing that is transferring everything except for the `node_modules` folder, as running `npm install` can [install OS-specific dependencies as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51725833/3170628).