# NodeJS/nextJS app is not running on windows machine

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

I'm developing a nextJS app on a macOS machine. After running `npm install`, I moved all the files to a windows (10) machine, which has no internet connection.
Running `npm run dev` is surprisingly not working. I do get an error which can be losley translated to `the command "next" is written wrongly or cannot be found`.

I do not see, what is wrong with my nextJS app - which is just the official example app, so it should work (and it is working on my macOS machine).

Is there any configuration missing on the windows machine? Running `node -v` and `npm -v` are returning the latest version.

**output**

```
C:\Users\User\nextjs-blog>npm run dev

> learn-starter@0.1.0 dev C:\Users\User\nextjs-blog
> next dev

Der Befehl "next" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! learn-starter@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the learn-starter@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-02T07_18_21_223Z-debug.log
```

**log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~predev: learn-starter@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~dev: learn-starter@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\User\nextjs-blog\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~dev: CWD: C:\Users\User\nextjs-blog
10 silly lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'next dev' ]
11 silly lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle learn-starter@0.1.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: learn-starter@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid learn-starter@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\User\nextjs-blog
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.18.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error learn-starter@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the learn-starter@0.1.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I deployed node.js app on CentOS with no internet connection.

Develop on Mac and yarn install, I moved all Files, but get errors on CentOS.

I finish that project with npm install with CentOS in virtual machine.

===

Here is not any miracles, and can not be option like npm install --linux-but-i-am-on-windows. You just need linux machine with interned to build your product on it (say perform npm install), and then copy project to the prod server. Jenkins or Bamboo could help

[Is there a difference between npm install on windows & linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724978/is-there-a-difference-between-npm-install-on-windows-linux)

Answer (score 0):

I have so many time this issue with reactjs or nextjs

**I first do**:

STEP 1: clear the cache
`npm cache clean --force`

STEP 2: delete `node-modules` and `package-lock-json`

`rm -rf node-modules package-lock-json` or remove them manuelly

STEP 3: install 'npm'

`npm install`

And then `npm start`

**If that FAIL**: you can debug on VSCode

On the `package.json' file click on` Debug` button

Chose the right select and the debug's extension will run and debug.

At the end `npm start` or 'npm run dev`

reactjs next.js `VSC`

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work if you run

npm install --force

that gets the app to show when I ran it on localhost:3000